# Postgres is not using CPU cores unsless running from psql or using "explain analyze"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Im running postgres 16.1 with a single user and no other activity on the server. I run this Test for many times and the results are very consistent.

**The Problem**

The query below will run with very consistent timings and the same execution plan (independt if server was started 3 seconds ago or run for weeks). But the total execution time is dependend if the query will be run from a SQL-client or from psql on the server.

The timing from any SQL-Client is about 3 times bigger in comparison to psql. But if i run the same query in a SQL-client but with

> explain analyse verbose timings wal buffers

the time is very comparable with psql execution.

The observation I made is, the execution over psql uses 5 cores corresponding to the setting ax_parallel_workers_per_gather=5. On the other hand, the execution from SQL-Client only uses 1 core and the execution time is about 90 seconds istead of 30.

Can you help me to elaborate on this?

```
2024-02-01 09:56:25.828 CET [650041] postgres@E_LOG:  duration: 29491.907 ms  plan:
    Query Text: WITH
    "x0" AS
        (
        SELECT
            "x1"."cal_dateid" AS "cal_dateid",
            "x1"."cal_dateint" AS "cal_dateint",
            "x1"."cal_date" AS "cal_date",
            "x1"."cal_year" AS "cal_year",
            "x1"."cal_month" AS "cal_month",
            "x1"."cal_day" AS "cal_day",
            "x1"."cal_yearmonth" AS "cal_yearmonth",
            "x1"."cal_datetext" AS "cal_datetext",
            "x1"."cal_yearmonthtext" AS "cal_yearmonthtext",
            "x1"."cal_monthtext" AS "cal_monthtext",
            extract(week from "x1"."cal_date") AS "c_date",
            "x1"."QWE" AS "QWE"
        FROM
            "public"."ABC" "x1"
        ),
    "DEF" AS
        (
        SELECT
            "x0"."cal_date" AS "cal_date",
            "x0"."cal_year" AS "cal_year"
        FROM
            "x0"
        )
    SELECT
        "DEF"."cal_year" AS "intr_year",
        SUM("ABC_ALL"."ID") AS "ID",
        COUNT(DISTINCT "ABC_ALL"."id") AS "id_sing",
        SUM("CDC"."SUM") AS "SUM_1"
    FROM
        "public"."ABC_2" "ABC_ALL"
            LEFT OUTER JOIN "DEF"
            ON "DEF"."cal_date" = "ABC_ALL"."date_occ"
                LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."case" "CDC"
                ON "CDC"."id_fk" = "ABC_ALL"."occ_id"
    GROUP BY
        "DEF"."cal_year"
    ORDER BY
        "intr_year" DESC NULLS last;
    GroupAggregate  (cost=1753092.95..5239798.05 rows=151 width=28)
      Group Key: x1.cal_year
      ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1753092.95..4973483.11 rows=26631343 width=26)
            Workers Planned: 5
            ->  Sort  (cost=1752092.87..1765408.54 rows=5326269 width=26)
                  Sort Key: x1.cal_year DESC NULLS LAST, ABC_ALL.id
                  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=164169.92..1084201.62 rows=5326269 width=26)
                        Hash Cond: (ABC_ALL.date_occ = x1.cal_date)
                        ->  Parallel Hash Right Join  (cost=162083.00..1068132.16 rows=5326269 width=26)
                              Hash Cond: (CDC.id_fk = ABC_ALL.occ_id)
                              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on case CDC  (cost=0.00..892067.69 rows=5326269 width=12)
                              ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=155333.00..155333.00 rows=540000 width=22)
                                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ABC_2 ABC_ALL  (cost=0.00..155333.00 rows=540000 width=22)
                        ->  Hash  (cost=1397.52..1397.52 rows=55152 width=8)
                              ->  Seq Scan on ABC x1  (cost=0.00..1397.52 rows=55152 width=8)
    JIT:
      Functions: 22
      Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell us many relevant details, but I guess that the “SQL client” is DBeaver or something else that uses the JDBC driver and limits the number of result rows with `java.sql.Statement.setMaxRows()`. Doing that disables the use of parallel query in PostgreSQL, which may well explain your performance problem.

See [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/parallel-query-postgresql-problems-jdbc-dbeaver/) for details.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the issue, albeit the problem occured not in DBeaver.